# Windows domain group policy settings for user lockdown

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a way in the domain group policies to limit the time users can lock the computer?  I have a number of users who logon and lock down Windows 7 systems and then walk away often forgetting the computer for days.  I don't want to prevent them from locking the computer, I just want to limit the time the computer is locked.

Comment: Do you want to limit their ability to lock the computer to certain times of day? Or have computer automatically unlock after a certain period of time? It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: It sounds to me that you are looking for the wrong thing.  Instead of worrying about them locking the computer, what you should be looking for is methods to automatically logout sessions that are idle/abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Check this in the Group policy Manager:

User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon/Logoff

On Windows 2008 R2

User configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Ctrl+Alt+Del ->Remove Lock Computer

This will prevent users from locking the workstation.  They then must logoff.

Comment: I doubt this is what he wants.